Composing with the zero morphism in a pre-additive category
In an pre-additive category $C$ let $X,Y$, and $Z$ be three objects, and let $f:X \to Y$ a morphism. If I compose $f$ with the zero morphism from $Y$ to $Z$ do I get the zero morphism from $X$ to $Z$?

You're missing an $X$ somewhere.

Thanks! It's fixed!

Yes you do. You have a factorisation though zero

@Julio: Can you explain this in more detail please?

I’ll write an answer

This also has nothing to do with being pre-additive.

@Randall since you don't have a zero object, how can you prove it without preadditiveness?

@julio_es_sui_glace  it's true for categories with zero object.  You don't need hom-set additiveness for that.

@Randall I know that but a pre additive category does not necessarily have a zero object. These are two different cases that are reunited when $C$ is additive

I changed to additive from pre-additive.

@julio_es_sui_glace  Ah, I see your point now.

@GheorgheBucătaru No need your original question was more interesting. I already answered both

Proof for pre additive (or $\operatorname{Ab}$-enriched) categories
An easy way to prove it (since you don't necessarily have a zero object) would be $2 \cdot (0 \circ f) = (2 \cdot 0 )\circ f = 0 \circ f$ by bilinearity of the composition.
Thus $0\circ f = 0$.
Proof for any category having a zero object.
Then if you work in any category having a zero object (which is the case for additive categories), you have the following.
Unfortunately we can only write rectangular diagrams on mathjax so mine will be a bit ugly.
Since by definition $0: Y \to Z$ is the composition of the unique morphisms $Y \to 0$ and $0 \to Z$, we have the commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{f}>> Y @>{0}>> Z\\
@VVV @VVV @AAA\\
0 @= 0 @= 0
\end{CD}$$

Note that this diagram commutes thanks to the properties of $0$ being a terminal object.

This means that $0\circ f$ is the composition of $X \to 0$ and $0 \to Z$ which is the zero morphism $0: X \to Z$.
If you wish to prove the dual statement, either work on $C^{\operatorname{op}}$ or adjust the diagram.

If you have as a definition $0$ is the neutral element of the additive group $\hom(X,Y)$ and you have a zero object, then you can easily prove that $h=(0 \to Y)\circ (X \to 0) = 0$ since we have by bilinearity
$$2h = (2\cdot(0 \to Y))\circ (X \to 0) = (0 \to Y)\circ (X \to 0) = h$$
thus $h = 0$, which means the two definitions coincide.
Note that we know $2 \cdot (0 \to Y) = 0$ since there is only one morphism from $Y$ to $0$.


Sorry but I don't see what $2h = (2.(0 \to Y)) \circ (X \to 0)$?

this is just the bilinearity of the composition: $2 \cdot (f \circ g) = (2\cdot f) \circ g = f \circ (2 \cdot g) $

Of course! Thanks!
